# How to stub export type by using sinon?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I create stub instance for the

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export type Translation = { [key: string]: string }
export type LoaderTranslations = { [key: string]: Translation }
```

**BaseLoader** abstract class:

```
import { LoaderTranslations } from './dictionary';

export abstract class BaseLoader {
    public abstract loadTranslations(items: string[]): Promise<LoaderTranslations>;
}
```

My tests:

```
import { BaseLoader } from './interface/base-loader';
import { LoadedTranslations } from './interface/dictionary';

describe(`test`, () => {

    let loaderMock: any,
        translations;

    beforeEach(() => {
        loaderMock = sinon.createStubInstance(BaseLoader);

        translations = sinon.createStubInstance(LoadedTranslations);

        // Then I want create spy for promise by using this translations stub
    });
});
```

I can't create stub for my `LoaderTranslations` dictionary. I got the following error:

> 'LoaderTranslation' only refers to a type, but being used as a value
>   here.

P.S. Sorry for a stupid question, but I have recently migrated from C# to TypeScript and it really difficult to me to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler performs *type erasure* which means types disappear in the compilation stage. That means you can't use types, or interfaces, as arguments or values in your runtime code.

To stub *something* you have to have a runtime visible *thing* to stub; like a class.

Simplistically, you could create an object that adheres to the `LoadedTranslations` type and either use it directly (as it is a stub, just not one generated by Sinon) - or pass it in to create a stub.